# Rattle(useGtkBuilder = TRUE) starts Rattle, but Rattle itself is frozen

Tags: rattle

I have version 3.4.0 of R. on Windows 7. I installed the library rattle. There were errors, but I found out from Stackoverflow that using `rattle( useGtkBuilder = TRUE)` solves the problem.

It did - only partially. Now, when I load the CSV file, and click on the execute button, in the Rattle GUI, nothing happens !

All the menu options are apparently working, but no file is getting loaded.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I could solve this problem, in the following way..

```
 >install.packages("rattle", repos="http://rattle.togaware.com", type="source")

>install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/RGtk2_2.20.31.zip", repos=NULL)

>library(RGtk2)

>library(rattle)

>rattle()
```

There were several messages asking me to install packages related to Cairo and XML, which i allowed to proceed.

Dont know why it exactly worked..but everything is working fine, and i ran a logistic regression model, and the results and the log-code, look just super.

Thanks and hope it helps other users, towards a simple/lucid way out,

Regards,
Raghavendra B

Answer (score 0):

As per the Rattle [trouble shooting page](https://rattle.togaware.com/rattle-install-troubleshooting.html), the current version of Rattle on CRAN has an issue with the most recent release of RGtk2 on CRAN. A fix is being readied for CRAN at present but in the meantime the following should fix it for RGtk2 2.20.33:

```
> install.packages("https://togaware.com/access/rattle_5.0.14.tar.gz",
                   repos = NULL,
                   type  = "source")
```